# Python - Should I use pygame.Rect or pygame.draw.[shape]?

Tags: python, pygame

Found this: [Why does pygame.draw.shape return a Rect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468472/why-does-pygame-draw-shape-return-a-rect)

So which one should I use? Is one faster than the other? Is there an advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: Unless you are running into framerate issues, the performance is less important than the readability. Which one makes it more clear what you are trying to do? My guess is `Rect`. Premature optimization causes more issues than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make sense.

[`pygame.Rect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910912/python-should-i-use-pygame-rect-or-pygame-draw-shape) is an object for storing rectangular coordinates

The functions in [`pygame.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) are used to draw simple shapes to a `Surface`.

There is no **or** here.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, as in the question I linked, it's also been proven that pygame.draw can also return a Rect (since it's drawing to a Surface). So, when creating a Rect variable within a class, is it better to use pygame.Rect or pygame.draw?

Comment: @Minighost If you want to set a variable to `0`, do you use the integer `0` or do you call `rm -rf ~/*` just because `rm` coincidentally returns `0` on success? If you need to store rectangular coordinates, use a `Rect`, if you need to draw on a Surface, use `pygame.draw...`. Just because `pygame.draw...` returns a `Rect` does not mean these things are interchangeable.